# concatenate .out files

Tags: bash, shell, cat, output

Can I combined multiple .out files with the cat command in bash or csh?  Additionally I want only the header of first file to be concatenated and I was thinking of using the tail function for that.  Anyone know if this is possible or of a way to do this?

Comment: `.out` files created by what?

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate files

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > output
```

To get the first N lines of a file

```
head -n N file
```

To get the first N lines of `file1` and then concatenate all the other files

```
head -n N file | cat - file1 file2 file3 > output
```

Cat will read standard input from the piped command (`-` argument) and concatenate it with the specified files.

See

- [`cat` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat)
- [`head` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head)

Answer (score 0):

If by .out you mean the binary executable files on linux then probably you will have to learn the eLF file format of linux to find the size of header and the using head you can concatenate the header of the file.